# Parsing Json in PHP, Printing specified area

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I am trying to print in php json value from json result (its in file).

I am able to get content as an array, but have a problem with printing it out:
that is my of json file:

```
{
   "GetUsers":[
      {
         "Language":"English",
         "Name":"StackOverFlowIsGreate",
         "UserId":"182024",
         "UserName":"ZiomusGorliczanin"
      }
   ],
   "Result":"Success",
   "Reason":""
}
```

Could any one help me with getting UserName and Language of my json file?
Thanks.
I only need to print it but can not figure out how can it be archived?

There is object from json:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (3) { ["GetUsers"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#2 (4) { ["Language"]=> string(7) "English" ["Name"]=> string(21) "StackOverFlowIsGreate" ["UserId"]=> string(6) "182024" ["UserName"]=> string(17) "ZiomusGorliczanin" } } ["Result"]=> string(7) "Success" ["Reason"]=> string(0) "" }
```

or Array:

```
array(3) { ["GetUsers"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["Language"]=> string(7) "English" ["Name"]=> string(21) "StackOverFlowIsGreate" ["UserId"]=> string(6) "182024" ["UserName"]=> string(17) "ZiomusGorliczanin" } } ["Result"]=> string(7) "Success" ["Reason"]=> string(0) "" }
```

Thanks.

Comment: what array you have got? Please add in your question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `json_decode()`

```
$j_decod = json_decode($json,true);

    echo j_decod['GetUsers'][0]['UserName'];  // Will return user name

    echo j_decod['GetUsers'][0]['Language'];  // Will return language
```

Comment: Thanks, its exactly what i needed, i need to get all arrays i think i could do it via foreach function ;) thanks.

Comment: For array 

$arrJson = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($arrJson ['items'] as $item)

{
 
  // Get username and language here

}

Comment: That is what i did to get all UserNames by specified MaxResult,`$count = 1;
$fMaxResult = $_GET["max"];//getting max result from variable posted by user
while($count <= $fMaxResult) {
 echo '<br>';
    echo $json_o['GetUsers'][$count]['UserName'];//ok as object
    $count++;
} `

Answer (score 1):

If you want object:

```
$decoded = json_decode($json);
echo $decoded->GetUsers[0]->UserName;
```

Or if you want array:

```
$decoded = json_decode($json, true);
echo $decoded['GetUsers'][0]['UserName'];
```